# How to extend a volume programmatically

Tags: c, windows, winapi, ntfs

My requirement is to extend drive volume through program. When I used IOCTL_DISK_GROW_PARTITION in DeviceIO to extend it, the disk management shows the new modified size while the size of the drive in This PC (My Computer) remains unchanged.

```
   BOOL DeviceIoControl(
      (HANDLE) hDevice,            // handle to device
      IOCTL_DISK_GROW_PARTITION,   // dwIoControlCode
      (LPVOID) lpInBuffer,         // input buffer
      (DWORD) nInBufferSize,       // size of the input buffer
      NULL,                        // lpOutBuffer
      0,                           // nOutBufferSize 
      (LPDWORD) lpBytesReturned,   // number of bytes returned
      (LPOVERLAPPED) lpOverlapped  // OVERLAPPED structure
    );
```

Through some analysis I found that while using this API the MBR of the disk is modified but the cluster bitmap of drive is not changed. I want to know the correct way of using this DeviceIO to expand a volume or some other API to do the same process.

Comment: with `IOCTL_DISK_GROW_PARTITION` you extend only partition from disk drive view. but you need extend file system also, which mounted this partition. i think need use [`FSCTL_EXTEND_VOLUME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364564(v=vs.85).aspx) for this *after* you extend partition

Comment: *The new volume size must be at least one cluster larger than the previous volume size. The underlying partition must have enough sectors to contain the extended volume. If not, IOCTL_DISK_GROW_PARTITION can be used if the underlying device has enough space available.* - so try `FSCTL_EXTEND_VOLUME` after `IOCTL_DISK_GROW_PARTITION`

Comment: and need use [`IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_DRIVE_SIZE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560419(v=vs.85).aspx) between `IOCTL_DISK_GROW_PARTITION` and `FSCTL_EXTEND_VOLUME`

Comment: Extend volume works by using IOCTL_DISK_GROW_PARTITION and FSCTL_EXTEND_VOLUME. When using IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_DRIVE_SIZE in between it returns error 112 (not enough space on disk). What is the role of IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_DRIVE_SIZE here, is it compulsory to use it?

Comment: `IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_DRIVE_SIZE` - how you call it ? you set `DISK_GEOMETRY dg;` as output buffer ?. simply from [`msdn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560376(v=vs.85).aspx)  - *Increases the size of an existing partition. It is used in conjunction with IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_DRIVE_SIZE to extend a disk, so that it will contain a new free space area, and then to extend an existing partition on the disk into the newly attached free space*

Comment: Thank you @RbMm. After using ' DISK_GEOMETRY dg; 'as output buffer, The code runs successfully.

Comment: yes, in my test also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

need understand different between disk driver, which maintain info about disk layout and partitions (it size, offset from disk begin, style (gpt or mbr) ) and file system, which mount this partition.

[`IOCTL_DISK_GROW_PARTITION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560376(v=vs.85).aspx) - this ioctl is handled by disk driver and extend partition, but this can not have effect for file system, which not handle this ioctl and have no knowledge at all that partition was extended. so you need additional ioctl use [`FSCTL_EXTEND_VOLUME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364564(v=vs.85).aspx) - this ioctl already send and handle to file-system.

so if we have to do next steps

1. send [`IOCTL_DISK_GROW_PARTITION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560376(v=vs.85).aspx) with
   [`DISK_GROW_PARTITION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552621(v=vs.85).aspx) as input buffer
2. send [`IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_DRIVE_SIZE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560419(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`DISK_GEOMETRY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552613(v=vs.85).aspx)
   as output buffer
3. send [`IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365180(v=vs.85).aspx) with
   [`PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365448(v=vs.85).aspx) as output for get actual size of
   partition now.
4. calculate new size of the volume, in sectors

   `LONGLONG SectorsPerPartition = PartitionEntry->PartitionLength.QuadPart / dg.BytesPerSector;`

   (*dg* we got at step 2 and *PartitionEntry* at step 3)
5. finally use [`FSCTL_EXTEND_VOLUME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364564(v=vs.85).aspx)

full code can be like next

```
int __cdecl SortPartitions(PPARTITION_INFORMATION_EX PartitionEntry1, PPARTITION_INFORMATION_EX PartitionEntry2)
{
    if (!PartitionEntry1->PartitionNumber) return PartitionEntry2->PartitionNumber ? -1 : 0;
    if (!PartitionEntry2->PartitionNumber) return +1;
    if (PartitionEntry1->StartingOffset.QuadPart < PartitionEntry2->StartingOffset.QuadPart) return -1;
    if (PartitionEntry1->StartingOffset.QuadPart > PartitionEntry2->StartingOffset.QuadPart) return +1;
    return 0;
}

DWORD ExtendTest(HANDLE hDisk)
{
    STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn;

    ULONG dwBytesRet;

    if (!DeviceIoControl(hDisk, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, NULL, 0, &sdn, sizeof(sdn), &dwBytesRet, NULL))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    if (sdn.DeviceType != FILE_DEVICE_DISK || sdn.PartitionNumber != 0)
    {
        return ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
    }

    GET_LENGTH_INFORMATION gli;

    if (!DeviceIoControl(hDisk, IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO, NULL, 0, &gli, sizeof(gli), &dwBytesRet, NULL))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    DbgPrint("Disk Length %I64x (%I64u)\n", gli.Length.QuadPart, gli.Length.QuadPart);

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX pdli;
    };

    ULONG cb = 0, rcb, PartitionCount = 4;

    for (;;)
    {
        if (cb < (rcb = FIELD_OFFSET(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX, PartitionEntry[PartitionCount])))
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (DeviceIoControl(hDisk, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX, NULL, 0, buf, cb, &dwBytesRet, NULL))
        {
            if (PartitionCount = pdli->PartitionCount)
            {
                PPARTITION_INFORMATION_EX PartitionEntry = pdli->PartitionEntry;

                qsort(PartitionEntry, PartitionCount, sizeof(PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX), 
                    (int (__cdecl *)(const void *, const void *))SortPartitions );

                do 
                {
                    if (!PartitionEntry->PartitionNumber)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    LARGE_INTEGER EndOffset; 
                    LARGE_INTEGER MaximumOffset = PartitionCount != 1 ? (PartitionEntry + 1)->StartingOffset : gli.Length;

                    EndOffset.QuadPart = PartitionEntry->StartingOffset.QuadPart + PartitionEntry->PartitionLength.QuadPart;

                    if (EndOffset.QuadPart > MaximumOffset.QuadPart)
                    {
                        //??
                        __debugbreak();
                    }
                    else if (EndOffset.QuadPart < MaximumOffset.QuadPart)
                    {
                        DISK_GROW_PARTITION dgp;
                        dgp.PartitionNumber = PartitionEntry->PartitionNumber;
                        dgp.BytesToGrow.QuadPart = MaximumOffset.QuadPart - EndOffset.QuadPart;

                        WCHAR sz[128];

                        swprintf(sz, L"\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\Harddisk%d\\Partition%u", sdn.DeviceNumber, dgp.PartitionNumber);

                        HANDLE hPartition = CreateFile(sz, FILE_READ_ACCESS|FILE_WRITE_ACCESS, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

                        if (hPartition != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                        {  
                            // +++ begin extend
                            BOOL fOk = FALSE;

                            DISK_GEOMETRY dg;
                            if (DeviceIoControl(hPartition, IOCTL_DISK_GROW_PARTITION, &dgp, sizeof(dgp), 0, 0, &dwBytesRet, 0) &&
                                DeviceIoControl(hPartition, IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_DRIVE_SIZE, 0, 0, &dg, sizeof(dg), &dwBytesRet, 0) &&
                                DeviceIoControl(hPartition, IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX, 0, 0, PartitionEntry, sizeof(*PartitionEntry), &dwBytesRet, 0)
                                )
                            {
                                LONGLONG SectorsPerPartition = PartitionEntry->PartitionLength.QuadPart / dg.BytesPerSector;

                                fOk = DeviceIoControl(hPartition, FSCTL_EXTEND_VOLUME, &SectorsPerPartition, 
                                    sizeof(SectorsPerPartition), 0, 0, &dwBytesRet, 0);

                            }

                            if (!fOk)
                            {
                                GetLastError();
                            }

                            //--- end extend
                            CloseHandle(hPartition);
                        }
                    }
                    // else EndOffset.QuadPart == MaximumOffset.QuadPart - partition can not be extended

                } while (PartitionEntry++, --PartitionCount);
            }

            return NOERROR;
        }

        switch (ULONG err = GetLastError())
        {
        case ERROR_MORE_DATA:
            PartitionCount = pdli->PartitionCount;
            continue;
        case ERROR_BAD_LENGTH:
        case ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
            PartitionCount <<= 1;
            continue;
        default:
            return err;
        }
    }

}
DWORD ExtendTest()
{
    HANDLE hDisk = CreateFileW(L"\\\\?\\PhysicalDrive0", FILE_GENERIC_READ|FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, 
        FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    if (hDisk != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD err = ExtendTest(hDisk);
        CloseHandle(hDisk);

        return err;
    }

    return GetLastError();
}
```